# Adding 2 Memo lines into ListView Items

Tags: delphi

I need to add Listview items from 2 Memos. I am using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

**Memo1 lines are as**

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

**Memo2 lines are as**

```
something1
something2
something3
something4
something5
```

Need to add these 2 Memo lines into Listview

**Listview Caption = Memo1 lines**

**Listview SubItem = Memo2 lines**

Need help

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

```
for var i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
begin
  var item := ListView.Items.Add;
  item.Caption := Memo1.Lines[i];
  item.SubItems.Add(Memo2.Lines[i];
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for var i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
begin
  var Item := ListView.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := Memo1.Lines[i];
  Item.SubItems.Add (Memo2.Lines[i]);
end;
```

Comment: But the problem is adding Memo2 as SubItem, how to do it .. because by using      for i := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count - 1 do
 ListView1.Items.Add.SubItems.Add(Memo2.Lines[i]); .. subitems does not appears opposite to captions it goes down where Memo1 lines as listview caption end

Comment: Because you are calling `ListView1.Items.Add()` too many times. Don't call it for each subitem added.

Comment: @robertjains sorry I misread your question, by the time I realized that,  Uwe Raabe posted the answer I was supposed to give at first place

Comment: Do we need two identical answers?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand you're right, there is no point of two identical answers, But please read my comment above to know why that happened, Sorry for inconvenience!

Comment: How Can I delete string which does not contain number with it like abc def67 , I need to delete abc because it does not have number with it

Comment: @robertjains you are asking a different question now, please open a new question thread.

Comment: @robertjains: Hint for your question: Use string helper function: if S.IndexOfAny (['0', '1',, '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] < 0 then delete (s)